# Model design for restaurant, meal and meal category

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-models

I am planning to develop a food delivery app from local restaurants. I am thinking for the best design. I have designed a json too for modeling API.However i am confuse with menu part. Should meal be in the restaurant as a foreign key or restaurant be a foreignkey in the meal.

Simple concept of my app is

A restaurant prepares various meals to serve various kind of customer. A meal is associated with category like a meal can be veg, non-veg. Customer(User) might order drinks too.

Is my model design and api design apt for such kind of scenario?

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    location = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
    features = models.ManyToManyField(FeatureChoice) # dinner, launch, nightlife,
    timing = models.ManyToManyField(TimingChoice) # sunday, monday, tuesday, 
    is_delivery = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal) main confusion is here


class Meal(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()


class MealCategory(models.Model)
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal)
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

**json design for REST API**

```
[
        {
            'name':'Kathmandu Fast Food',
            'owner':'Sanskar Shrestha',
            'location':'Koteshwor',
            'city':'Kathmandu',
            'features':[
                {
                    'features':'Breakfast'
                },

                {
                    'features':'Launch'
                },

                {
                    'features':'NightLife'
                },

            ],

            'timings':[
                {
                    'timing':'MOnday'
                },

                {
                    'timing':'Sunday'
                },
            ],

            'is_delivery':'true',
            'menu':[
                {
                    'name':'Chicken BBQ',
                    'price':990,
                    'quantity':10,
                    'image':'localhost:8000/media/.../',
                    'category':{
                        'name':'Non-veg'
                    }
                },

                {
                    'name':'Veg Chowmin',
                    'price':160,
                    'quantity':20,
                    'image':'localhost:8000/media/',
                    'category':
                        {
                            'name':'Veg'
                        }
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

Please do share your expertise thought.

Answer (score 0):

Meal should has MealCategory as a ForeignKey. I think that Meal is a model which should be independent of restaurant. Think about add another model

```
class RestaurantMeal(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal)
```

to store data about meals in particular restaurants.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about my Json? Does that design looks good? Do you think there should be much more to cover the relation of restaurant, meal and meal category for better service?

Comment: In my opinion JSON looks fine, I will change only one thing: on features and timings return just a list with features/timings not a list of dicts

Comment: What should i do for returning just a list for features and timings? Do i have to work on Django Rest Framework for that? Can your provide a hint?

Comment: I definitely reccomend django rest framework for REST API, it has a lot of features which will be helpful for you app. In serializer you can specify a type of field

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you have `restaurant = models.ForeignKey(User)` in `Meal` model when you should have `restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant')`
2. `MealCategory` should be independent, not belonging to `Meal`, on the contrary, `Meal` should belong to `MealCategory`.
3. `price` field should be `Decimal`
4. Why does `rating` is Integer? Have you ever seen rating ever been integer? It's integer only if one person rated it.

   ```
   class Meal(models.Model):
       restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant')
       name = models.CharField()
       price = models.DecimalField()
       quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
       image = models.ImageField()
       rating = models.FloatField()
       meal_category = models.ForeignKey('MealCategory')


   class MealCategory(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField()
       slug = models.SlugField()
   ```

Comment: For the first point, its a typo. Regarding 3rd point i was going to write IntegerField but wrote FloatField. If the price is in dollar, Decimal would be great but in the context of Nepal's currency integer would work. For other point thanks a lot for clearing the problem.